# Can I alt-tab windows from all workspaces?

Tags: 12.04, workspaces

I put certain windows on certain spaces, but prefer alt-tab to switch between them. Is there a toggle or other option to turn on the alt-tab from all workspaces in unity?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[image]

In 12.04, the switcher defaults to those windows co-located on one workspace/viewport.

You have a couple of options in `ccsm`

[image]

You can untick the *bias* option which will show windows in all workspaces.

Alternatively, you can use add <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to your <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to achieve the same effect

Comment: Just for the record, to find this panel, you need to open the Ubuntu Unity Plugin in the compiz manager

Comment: +1 because of the »add CTRL to your ALT+TAB« hint

Answer (score 4):

CompizConfig Settings Manager is deprecated, another tool to use is `gconf-editor`.

Navigate to

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/
```

and set the proper key bindings for `alt_tab_forward` and `alt_tab_forward_all`. By default, Ctrl+Alt+Tab switches between windows on all workspaces, and Alt+Tab between windows on current one. I'd just swap them.

Or from the command line:

```
gconftool --set --type=string /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/alt_tab_forward_all '<Alt>Tab'
gconftool --set --type=string /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/alt_tab_forward '<Control><Alt>Tab'
```

You may also want to fix `alt_tab_prev` and `alt_tab_prev_all` accordingly (I personally never use them).

Comment: gconf is being phased out itself in favor of dconf.

Comment: So...which tool should be used by an inexperienced (or lazy) Ubuntu user? I'd rather not have to learn `gconf-editor` or `dconf` if the CompozConfig Settings Manager is still around. (Is there harm in using the CCSM for now?)

Answer (score 0):

**No-new-software** based solution:

Based on Yevgen Yampolskiy's suggestion in [Alt-Tab does not switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135685/alt-tab-does-not-switch) , 
I renamed the .gconf* and .gnome2* folders in my home folder to ..gconf* and ..gnome2*, logged out, and back in.
**Problem solved**.  By the way, I had been using 12.04 for 8 months until this problem struck after I stupidly did 
`sudo service lightdm restart` 
from an F1 console session. Stupidly, because I was running gnome classic without effects.