# Alt-Tab does not switch

Tags: window-manager

Since upgrading to 12.04, my alt-tab occasionally does not work. I cannot determine the symptoms that lead to it, but there are some windows that just decide not to show. What happens is I alt-tab to a given window, say the terminal, and instead of showing it, I just see it wobble like a notification in the list of programs down the left. Is this a bug?

Comment: Isn't this a  bug, and so off-topic for the site?

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/956318/126417) worked for me

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, I noticed that too! I'm surprised they forgot something as important as that.

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager:

To open terminal hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following commands:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Or search for `compizconfig-settings-manager` in Software Center and install from there.

Then go to System Tools > Preferences > CompizConfig, if you can't find System Tools, look for `CompizConfig Settings Manager` in Unity Dash.

Go at the very bottom where it says Windows Management

Put a check-mark in Application Switcher

### That should fix it.

Go to System Tools > Preferences > CompizConfig or search for`CompizConfig Settings Manager` in Unity Dash. Then,
Windows Manager-Application Switcher. click on Next window-alt-tab click it.
click on ''Grab key Combination'', here actually use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, & it will grab it.
OK

Comment: Work great! But it is totally crazy! How could I have figured it out from nowhere?...

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, not even in conjunction with  disabling the Unity Switcher, but Gordon's suggestion did.

Comment: @Matthew Finally got it to work: in ccsm > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher, ensure <Alt>Tab is set for "Key to start the switcher", then "Back", *then* click the checkbox (to get it checked) near Ubuntu Unity Plugin - after a few warnings and key conflicts resolution, that should work!

Comment: Better yet for gnome classic users: when log in, just ensure (click the foot icon) to start Gnome classic **No effects**. The no-effect version seems to have Alt-tab working.

Comment: compiz crashes every time on my office computer, so i decided to not install it on my laptop. But I have some problems with alt+tab. sometimes some programs do not appear there or simply disappear

Comment: In case de Application Switcher is not present, also run "sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra"

Answer (score 21):

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-classic (without effects, so no Compiz) and the above doesn't work.

The fix, from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126205/alttab-not-switching-between-windows-on-12-04) is actually easier than you'd expect:

- Go to 'Applications','System Tools','System Settings'
- Click 'Keyboard'
- Click the 'Shortcuts Tab'
- Click 'Navigation' on the left
- In the right-hand pane click on 'Switch applications' and press Alt-Tab to assign that as the accelerator.

Comment: Im also using gnome-classic, my shortcut for switch application is alt+tab and it still does not work... ?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: It stopped working for me as well. I ended up removing .gconf* and .gnome2* folders - it started working. Proper fix would be to remove or edit one of the configuration files, but I do not have time to investigate

Comment: it works for me on VB Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

In case Application switcher, doesnt work (like the 1st answer), check the static application switcher in CCSM. It works fine for me.