# Alt-tab freezes windows and many programs

Tags: 12.04, compiz

Per [this thread and its solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/136722/24203), I'm using `compiz` for enabling alt-tab window switch. It had been working as expected for a few days, but today suddenly it started to freeze the entire display. Since it stops responding with its keyboard & mouse, I have to login via ssh and reboot (I just wanted to be as nice as possible to the system). Any idea is appreciated.

Just describing my environment more precisely, I use this problematic Ubuntu (12.04, `Gnome Classic`) machine from Mac via `synergy` 1.3.6. And I particularly see this issue happen when I switch to `filezilla` (FTP client). With `Gnome Classic (no effect)` I've not seen this.

Comment: Have you looked on Launchpad to see if this bug has already been reported? If you search for "alt-tab freezes" on https://launchpad.net/ you will see a lot of bugs; I suggest you read through them to see if one exactly matches your problem. If none of them match, please take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @David Edwards I've searched through launchpad.net but haven't found the report that exactly the same with mine. Think I issue a report (not sure if the phenomenon I'm seeing is bug or spec though).

Comment: @fossfreedom Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the link you cited tell that you should provide a link to the specific issue report when you close a question? I asked my question because I didn't know if it's bug nor already reported. If I already knew the phenomenon I asked was a bug, I hadn't asked here...

Comment: @IsaacS - remember, Ask Ubuntu is not a bug-tracker.  Freezes in applications and desktops is not a usual occurrence and as such are not a good fit for Ask Ubuntu.  This should be reported as a launchpad bug (instructions in the link) - the developers will decide if this is a duplicate of another bug.

Comment: @fossfreedom ok I understand and will report on launchpad. Still I'm glad that I asked this here b/c experienced users like you told me it could be a bug :)