# Alt+tab, switching between applications in 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Apparently this function has been lost with the new update to 14.04. I write as an end user who relies on this function to limit pain from wrist RSI. Has this been replaced with a new keyboard short cut? I really hope so as this will seriously impact my life in a negative way otherwise!

Comment: The shortcut is still present in 14.04. Are you sure your keys are working properly? Holding down your super key(the key with the windows logo on it) will show the popular shortcuts available.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/136722/270074)?

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer. I've tried it on a couple of keyboards with the same effect. Holding down the key with the windows logo does nothing so far!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your configuration is broken. To test this, create a new user and log in as the new user. Check if the keyboard combinations work now (hold <kbd>Super</kbd> to see some available combinations).

If it works for the new user, I'd recommend resetting Unity for the old user. Just install *unity-tweak-tool* from the repositories and run `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` from a terminal.

Comment: thanks for your answer, still no idea what the problem is but have forwarded your suggestion to someone who will understand it!