# alt + tab not working to switch between windows

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, application-switcher

I have Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

I'm working between two open windows (Using google and at the same time another program) but when I try the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> like in Windows, nothing happens. I also tried with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (nothing happens), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (switches between tabs in google, not what I want) and Super+Tab (it pops up the menu, not what I want).

Is there a way I can enable this function? I see in many articles that the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works with Ubuntu, I don't know why it doesn't work in my computer.

Comment: Have you looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/135685/alt-tab-does-not-switch?

Comment: I followed the command and it didn't work. I installed CompizConfig but the changes didn't work.

Comment: I followed these instructions: https://people.gnome.org/~federico/blog/alt-tab.html

Comment: I believe unity comes default on 16.04 but do not hold me to it...

Comment: @NerdOfCode Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Unity. On 17.10 and up, Ubuntu comes with GNOME.

Comment: @PerlDuck Just making sure because your link is for gnome and we assume he is talking about unity

Comment: Yes I don't have gnome

Comment: @NerdOfCode Oh, Unity is a shell on the GNOME DE.